# Probability of neither A nor B occurring when not mutually exclusive

Tags: probability

I have a homework question that reads: The probability that an integrated circuit chip will have defective etching is 0.12 (A), the probability that it will have a crack defect is 0.29 (B), and the probability that it has both defects is 0.07. 
What is the probability that a newly manufactured chip will have neither defect?

I figured that the probability of neither occurring would simply be the probability of A not occurring multiplied by the probability of B not occurring, so I got .88 * .71 = .625. But then I realized that I'm not taking into account when they BOTH happen. Should I be including that possibility and thus my figure should be .88 * .71 * .93 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

Total probability and De'Morgan's together imply $P(A\cup B)=1-P(A^c\cap B^c)$

Inclusion-exclusion implies $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$

> The problem tells you the values of $P(A),P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$ and asks you to find $P(A^c\cap B^c)$

---

As an additional aside.  In your attempt, you were multiplying probabilities.  I will emphasize that $P(A\cap B)$ is **not** equal to $P(A)\times P(B)$ in general scenarios.  $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ is true **if and only if** $A$ and $B$ are independent events, meaning that when $A$ and $B$ are not independent that would mean that $P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)\times P(B)$.  If you are unsure of whether or not they are independent, then you simply may not use this.

Instead, the more correct statement is that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B\mid A)=P(B)\times P(A\mid B)$, but that is completely unhelpful for this problem as this does not get us closer to our goal.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So my answer is .66?

Comment: That is correct.